# view or test mini sites locally in Safari browser with relative source references iPad iOS 15.x and higher

Tags: ipad, safari, software-recommendation, pdf

**Project goal:**

Publish **on iPad** html/css static **multi page site**, external style sheet, images, and maybe animated GIF clips or very short videos.

**This must run offline from iPad Files storage no calls to server.**

**Problem:**
Apple at some point disabled the ability to open local files in Safari. This means you cannot open an HTML file with relative src references such as img src= or <link rel="stylesheet" href=".
**You can only "open" or view the file via the Files app on iPad**.
I have tried to hack around this for previewing my work via developer mode, cabled iPad as an exercise in futility.

**Current Project state and or Limitation:**

"Publish" or saved single file HTML document to the iPad.

View file in Safari - **Unable**

File-name.html view via iOS Files app

Files app renders the html file with only the internal text and internal header contained CSS styling.

**Files app fails to load all relative source references such as**  `<img src="test-image.png" alt="grrrrrr" />`

Is there a iOS app available that will load and run a static site essentially just like any browser normally would on MacOS desktop environment ?

A MacOS application that would essentially export a whole **multi page mini site** as a webarchive if you will that Safari on iPad would render correctly ?

Maybe some Adobe Acrobat Pro functionality and or InDesign etc that would export some type of PDF chunk that would render as planned either in Safari or Acrobat Reader just like it should in the first place.....

Apple seriously smh

Thanks.

Comment: Something like https://apps.apple.com/ch/app/worldwideweb-mobile/id1623006812 ?

Comment: If this doesn’t solve your problem, please edit the question to provide more focus on the problem you want to solve.

Comment: Thanks nohillside gets me 99% there on initial 5 minutes of rough testing with iPad Pro 11 inch 3rd Gen 15.5. - <img src= relative ref tests good
Of course the app would have to be installed for all motivated users plus step by step screen shot style instructions...
It is a free app , stunningly so, thanks Craig Hockenberry

https://blog.iconfactory.com/2022/06/worldwideweb-part-2/

https://apps.apple.com/ch/app/worldwideweb-mobile/id1623006812?platform=ipad